# Native C++ Asynchronous background thread with a return value, main thread can not be blocked

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm struggling with the idea of background threads in C++.
When I start my application, a thread begins operating in the background for a while. When it is finished, I need to display a message box (whose content depends on the thread's result) and call a function, both on the main thread. While the background thread is running, the application must remain responsive to the user.

I looked at **std::future**, but that still requires me to either block the main thread or to have some sort of loop running in the main thread that checks the result periodically. But this loop would also have to run asynchronously, leading to the same issue again.
Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: why you dont call function and also show message from that thread instead of main thread and synchronize them with mutex?

Comment: @N0ll_Boy it's not a UI thread. Does that even work?

Comment: if you use `std::bind` with `std::function` it will work. but i suggest you to use event loop concept in main thread and do other ui and call functions on other threads.

Comment: I'll look into both of those options, thank you.